# Double value with two decimal using NumberFormat

Tags: java, format, double, precision, number-formatting

I am using `java.text.NumberFormat` to convert my double value to two decimal with conman separate format.

My code of line is:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(53508));
```

This code will convert 53508 to 53,508 format but I require in 53,508.00 format (with 2 decimal).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks Friends I solve it .... :)

Below is line of code

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

System.out.prinitln(formatter.format(53508));
```

and output is

```
53,508.00
```

Comment: Is there a way to chain these? Instead of making each its own line

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    String s = f.format(53508);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Kotlin :

```
val n = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
n.maximumFractionDigits = 2
n.minimumFractionDigits = 2
```

And after format your number with :

```
n.format(53508)
```